# finding sum of fractions n/1 to 1/n

Tags: python

I am trying to find the sum `n/1 + (n-1)/2 + (n-2)/3 ... + 1/n`. I am not getting the correct output

This is what I have

```
n = int(input("Please enter a positive integer: "))

sum2 = 0.0

for i in range(1, n-1):
    sum2 = sum2 + (i/1)

print("For n =", n, "the sum n/1 + (n-1)/2 + ... 1/n is", sum2)
```

My expected output for `sum2` is `11.15` when `6` is entered as `n` but it's not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What output **are** you getting? Have you used a debugger?

Comment: Notice the denominator needs to change in your second sum. Does it change in your second loop? How would you get it to change the way you want it to change? What is the pattern here?

Comment: For sum2 you're adding up all integers. Why should you get 11.15?

Comment: `(i/1)` - are you sure about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When talking about the 2nd summation, besides the numerator decreasing one by one, the denominator also needs to increase one by one.

```
n = int(input("Please enter a positive integer: "))


sum2 = 0

for i in range(0, n):
    sum2 = sum2 + (n-i)/(i+1)

print("For n =", n, "the sum n/1 + (n-1)/2 + ... 1/n is", sum2)
```